# Що таке "покренчіло" в пісні "Міську вважай"?

Tags: значення-слів

У пісні "[Міську, вважай](https://youtu.be/t_4-ub3q1IA)" гурту Брати Гадюкіни:

> Перше травня, пасха, зелені свята
> Hімці, жиди, поляки, цось мі сє **покренчіло**
> Вперед поволи граєм собі вар’ята
> Бачимо третім воком же ніц сі не змінило

Що таке "покренчіло"?

Я шукав у словнику UKRLIT.ORG по корню кренчіти - немає результатів

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Це радше не корїнь, а [дїєіменник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2).

Слово не шукаїть ся, бо це схоже на польське, де зберїг ся носовий з гиншою голосною *ǫ* [он] → *ę* [ен]  і відбула ся зміна *ti* [ті] → *ci* [чї], тобто [*kręcić*](//wsjp.pl/haslo/podglad/16350/krecic) [кренчїчь]. Ві квадратних дужках приблизна вимова державною абеткою.

Поруч стоїть *сє* — теж частина дїєслова і скорїш за всього від того ж польського *się* [шє], бо в подальшому бачимо *сі*, що звичнїший до української. Тому повний дїєйменник: [*pokręcić się*](//wsjp.pl/haslo/do_druku/52569/pokrecic-sie), де можна знайти і вираз *цошь шє покренчїло*: *stać się pogmatwanym i przez to niejasnym*, тобто щось на зразок *стало заплутано, а тому неясно*.

Для порівняння, стандартна українська зазнала таких змін: *ǫ* [он] → *у* і *ti* → *ти*, де в підсумку *крутити* → *покрутитися*, однак, як на мене, *перемішатися* чи *закрутитися* за значїннями будуть ближчими.

Comment: Перепрошую за відхилення від теми, але вже не вперше помічаю, тож цікавить:
звідки походять незвичні до сучасної мови елементи у вашій відповіді, як то «ї» замість «і» («шукаїть ся», « скорїш»), «ві», і тому подібне?

Comment: @rkiyanchuk, якщо Ви не заперечуєте, спробую відповісти на Ваш коментар замість Bocchi. [Отут про «ї» замість «і»](/q/7158). А «ві» — це, власне, цілком словниковий (хоч і рідковживаний) варіант прийменника [«в, у (ув, во, вві, уві, ві)»](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=6305&page=230), наприклад «Наступила весна ві всій своій красі» (Олександр Кониський) чи [«Швидко й гарно, як ві сні»](https://tsn.ua/svit/avstraliya-rozshirila-sankciyi-proti-rosiyi-hto-u-spisku-2170909.html) (віршик з газети) — інша справа, що Bocchi вживає цей варіант частіше й ширше, ніж сучасні мовці.